# Python Data Frame | Extract part of a text from a column into 3 new columns

Tags: python, text, split

I hope you are doing well.
I have a pandas data frame with a column containing with the following patterns "Region/Country/City".
I need to create 3 new columns : Region, Country and City assigning its corresponding values.
I appreciate your support and collaboration on guidance to solve this.

Many thanks
Hernan

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.Series.str.split('/', expand=True)

ex:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'data': ['Region/Country/City']
})

a[['region', 'country', 'city']] = a['data'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```